# Delete one-to-one: Hibernate 3 + Spring 3 + PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, one-to-one, hibernate-cascade

This is my first post and I am new to Hibernate + Spring. I am using XML for Hibernate mapping declaration in my applicationContext.xml file.

Briefly, I am trying to do:

```
parent.setChild(null);
parentDao.update(parent);
```

With the hope that it will delete the child. But it doesn't work. :(

Instead, I've got this Exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.EntityEntry.getLoadedValue(EntityEntry.java:255)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:232)   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:127)    at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cascadeOnUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:376)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:350)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:246)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultUpdateEventListener.java:57)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireUpdate(SessionImpl.java:742)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:730)  at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:722)   at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$14.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:708)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.update(HibernateTemplate.java:705)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.update(HibernateTemplate.java:701)
>     at
>   fr.gouv.travail.gestionAccords.server.dao.implementations.DossierDAOImpl.update(DossierDAOImpl.java:163)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>     at $Proxy38.update(Unknown Source)  at
>   fr.gouv.travail.gestionAccords.server.business.gestionDossiers.detailsDossier.commons.implementations.DetailsDossierBusinessImpl.update(DetailsDossierBusinessImpl.java:396)

I've seen that I have to declare `delete-orphan` in my XML mapping file but it's getting me crazy because it doesn't want to work. Could you please have a look at what is wrong?

So, in my current project I have a one-to-one relationship: here is my XML mapping for the parent called ***DossierBean***.

***DossierBean.hbm.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="fr.gouv.travail.gestionAccords.server.dao.beans.pojo.DossierBean" table="dos">
    <id name="numeroDossier" type="string">
        <column name="num_dos" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>

    <one-to-one name="travailleurHandicape" class="fr.gouv.travail.gestionAccords.server.dao.beans.pojo.TravailleurHandicapeBean" cascade="all,delete-orphan" lazy="false" />
    // Other properties...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

***TravailleurHandicapeBean.hbm.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="fr.gouv.travail.gestionAccords.server.dao.beans.pojo.TravailleurHandicapeBean" table="tha">
        <id name="numeroDossier" type="string">
            <column name="num_dos" />
                <generator class="foreign">
                    <param name="property">dossier</param>
                </generator>
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="dossier" class="fr.gouv.travail.gestionAccords.server.dao.beans.pojo.DossierBean" constrained="true" />
        <property name="dateAgrement" column="dt_agrement" type="date"/>
        <property name="dureeAgrement" column="dur_agrement" type="integer"/>
        <property name="indicateurRenouv" column="ind_renouv" type="character"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

***DossierBean.java (Parent bean)*** :

```
@Named("dossierBean")
@Scope("prototype")
public class DossierBean
{
     private String numeroDossier;  // PK
     private TravailleurHandicapeBean travailleurHandicape; // One-to-one relation

   /**
    * @return the numeroDossier
    */
    public String getNumeroDossier()
    {
            return numeroDossier;
    }

   /**
    * @param numeroDossier the numeroDossier to set
    */
    public void setNumeroDossier(String numeroDossier) 
    {
            this.numeroDossier = numeroDossier;
    }

   /**
    * @return the travailleurHandicape
    */
    public TravailleurHandicapeBean getTravailleurHandicape() 
    {
            return travailleurHandicape;
    }

   /**
    * @param travailleurHandicape the travailleurHandicape to set
    */
    public void setTravailleurHandicape(TravailleurHandicapeBean travailleurHandicape)
    {
            this.travailleurHandicape = travailleurHandicape;
    }
}
```

***TravailleurHandicapeBean.java (Child bean) :***

```
@Named("travailleurHandicapeBean")
@Scope("prototype")
public class TravailleurHandicapeBean
{
    private String numeroDossier;
    private DossierBean dossier;
    private Date dateAgrement;
    private Integer dureeAgrement;
    private Character indicateurRenouv;

   /**
    * @return the numeroDossier
    */
    public String getNumeroDossier()
    {
            return numeroDossier;
    }

   /**
    * @param numeroDossier the numeroDossier to set
    */
    public void setNumeroDossier(String numeroDossier)
    {
            this.numeroDossier = numeroDossier;
    }

   /**
    * @return the dateAgrement
    */
    public Date getDateAgrement()
    {
            return dateAgrement;
    }

   /**
    * @param dateAgrement the dateAgrement to set
    */
    public void setDateAgrement(Date dateAgrement)
    {
            this.dateAgrement = dateAgrement;
    }

   /**
    * @return the dureeAgrement
    */
    public Integer getDureeAgrement()
    {
            return dureeAgrement;
    }

   /**
    * @param dureeAgrement the dureeAgrement to set
    */
    public void setDureeAgrement(Integer dureeAgrement)
    {
            this.dureeAgrement = dureeAgrement;
    }

   /**
    * @return the indicateurRenouv
    */
    public Character getIndicateurRenouv() 
    {
            return indicateurRenouv;
    }

   /**
    * @param indicateurRenouv the indicateurRenouv to set
    */
    public void setIndicateurRenouv(Character indicateurRenouv)
    {
            this.indicateurRenouv = indicateurRenouv;
    }

   /**
    * @return the dossier
    */
    public DossierBean getDossier() 
    {
            return dossier;
    }

   /**
    * @param dossier the dossier to set
    */
    public void setDossier(DossierBean dossier)
    {
            this.dossier = dossier;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

No answers ? Thanks for your contribution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this bug report on Hibernate:
https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5267
Appears to be exactly your issue. I'm not sure if it only affects version 3.5 or 4.x as well.

Workaround appears to be calling session.merge() instead of session.saveOrUpdate()

Comment: This is exactly my problem. Thank you for your help. I have finally ended with a workaround : delete all the childs TravailleurHandicapeBean and saveAll new TravailleurHandicapeBean which are present in the parent one. :)